# If a measure is $\sigma -$finite, why is finite on the compacts set?

Tags: measure-theory, compactness

Let $X$ a topological space and $\mathcal B$ the Borel set of $X$. Let $\mu$ a measure on $\mathcal B$. Why if $\mu$ is $\sigma -$finite, then $\mu(K)<\infty $ for all compact $K\subset X$ ?

**Attempts**

Let $\{X_i\}$ a collection of $X$ s.t. $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ and $\mu(X_i)<\infty $ for all $i$. Let $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$ opens s.t. $$K\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^nU_i\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i.$$

I would agree if each $U_i$ is contained in a finite number of $X_j$, but I don't understand why it is really the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $X=\mathbb Q$ (with the usual topology) and $\mu(A)=\#A$. Then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, but$$\mu\left(\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}\right)=\infty,$$in spite of the fact that $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is compact.

Comment: Looks to be a very good example, thank you. Something is nevertheless strange : In a book I'm reading, they say that a $\mu:\mathcal B\to [0,\infty ]$ is a Radon measure if $\mu(K)<\infty $ on compact set. And on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure) they say that a measure is a Radon measure if it's inner regular, outer regular and $\sigma -$finite. So both definition should be equivalent no ?

Comment: @Henri I suppose that, yes, they are equivalent. However, the measure that I defined is neither a Radon measuere nor outer regular.

Comment: Oh, true. In my mind I was thinking about $\mu$ more regular. But anyway, in fact your answer gave me a better idea of "having more regularity". So perfect. Just a last small thing : If $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal B$ its borel $\sigma -$algebra, is it true that $X$ is a countable union of compact set ? If no, what condition we have to put on the topology to have the statement true ? (I know for example it's true in $\mathbb R^n$ with standard topology).

Comment: @Henri No. If, in $\mathbb R$, you consider the discrete topology, then $\mathbb R$ cannot be expressed as a countable union of compact subsets (which are the finite subsets, in this context).

Comment: I'm confuse on something : you say that $K:=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N^*\}$ is compact in $\mathbb Q$. $\mathcal U=\{\{0\},\{\frac{1}{n}\}\mid n\in\mathbb N^*\}$ is a covering of open set of $K$. What would be a finite subcovering of $K$ by element of $\mathcal U$ ?

Comment: @Henri I forgot to mention that the topology that I had in mind for $\mathbb Q$ was the usual one. I've edited my answer.

Comment: By usual you mean the one induced by the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y |$ ?

Comment: @Henri Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think there are some  mistakes in your first comment. There are different non-equivalent definitions of Radon measures. Sigma finiteness is usually not part of the definition. The fact that any Borel  measure finite on compact sets  is regular  is true in some spaces but not in a general topological space. I am just clarifying these points for the benefit of OP . Your answer is good.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your enlightening comments.